# How do I query by post format in WordPress 3.1

Tags: query-posts, customization, post-formats

I am trying to query for all posts with a post format of 'quote.' I have added the post formats to my functions.php with

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'image', 'video', 'gallery', 'quote' ) );
```

I have selected 'quote' as the format for the post in the admin. The last example under [Taxonomy_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters) shows how to display posts that have the 'quote' format but when I run it in my theme no posts are returned. Here is the code:

```
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post-format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'post-format-quote'
    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

When I just query all posts and place

```
echo get_post_format();
```

in the loop it returns the word 'quote' on the front-end. Also, when I var_dump() the query I do not see anything in the array about post format.

Does anyone know if it is possible to query by post format? If so how?

EDIT - See 5 comment under Bainternet's answer:
This is the code found on index.php of the twentyten theme of a fresh install trying to return format type quotes. I return 'no' instead of 'quote'. Can you see anything that I should change.

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php $args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post-format',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array('quote')
        )
      )
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      echo get_post_format();
    endwhile; else:
      echo 'no';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();      
    ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

EDIT 2 - It appears that the WordPress Codex has now changed and the portion on Taxonomy Parameters is only found in Google cache.

EDIT 3 - FINAL WORKING CODE

```
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'post-format-quote'
    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

The twenty-ten edit from the first edit will be...

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php $args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'post-format-quote'
        )
      )
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_title();
      echo get_post_format();
      echo '<br />';
    endwhile; else:
      echo 'no';
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();      
    ?>
  </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is incorrect! You have

```
'taxonomy' => 'post-format'
```

But it really needs to be:

```
'taxonomy' => 'post_format'
```

Without the underscore, the query will be invalid. I just tested this on my WordPress 3.1 install after pulling my hair out for hours.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you very much for catching that. I could swear that I copied the original code directly from the Codex page. (Maybe it was wrong there as well at one time.) It works now. Along with changing it to post_format I also needed to change 'terms' => 'quote' back to 'terms' => 'post-format-quote'. For anyone else interested please see Edit 3 of the original post for the final code.

Comment: Sure, glad I was able to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

in `tax_query` "terms" accepts array so you need to put `post-format-quote` in an array like this:

```
$args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post-format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('post-format-quote')
    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this and gotten it to work. I added the array part and it still did not return anything. Is post-format-quote the correct slug to put in the array?

Comment: no its not you need to put the post format it self like "quote" and not post-format-quote

Comment: Do you mean I should put 'terms' => array('quote') since that is what I have quote defined as up in the add_theme_support function? I tried that as well. Still no luck.

Comment: well 'terms' => array('quote') is working form me, try to echo out the post format with 'echo get_post_format();' and see what you get

Comment: Ok, so when I echo that I get 'quote'. In a moment of desperation I have turned off all plugins and switched back to the default twentyten theme, and created 3 test posts, one with a format of quote. I have updated the functions.php file to add quote to the add_theme_support call and updated index.php to use the following code: [see edit at bottom of original post]