# Help altering a query to exclude all but standard post format

Tags: query-posts, post-formats

I feel like I've been banging my head against the keyboard for a week with this problem. I'm trying to change my current query on my home page to show only posts that are set as **standard** posts using the new post format.

I've looked everywhere for answers (including [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11764/display-query-post-formats/12718) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10855/how-do-i-query-by-post-format-in-wordpress-3-1)) and tried everything I've found, but I can't get it to work within the framework of my current query.

My query is provided below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php     
query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => $ids, 'showposts' => 10, 'cat' => '-4' ) ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
-LOOP STUFF-
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?><BR>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**UPDATE - March 30:** Since I posted this I found out how to properly query for, we'll say, image posts using this code:

```
    <?php 
$args = array(
  'post__not_in' => $ids, 
  'showposts' => 10, 
  'cat' => '-4,-1866,-27',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'post-format-image'
    )
  )
);        
    query_posts( $args ); ?>
<!-- Look Stuff -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But I still need to figure out how to do the opposite and only pull **standard** posts.

**Second Update - March 30:** I found the answer after some more hunting. Apparently the only way to pull the standard posts is to add:

'operator' => 'NOT IN',

So it looks for posts that aren't in the image post format. Or I have to add an array of terms to the terms line so it won't return any of those formats. Odd, but it works.

Comment: As a minor addendum, perhaps the site needs a tag for post format now?

Comment: you dont need to exlclude all other posts formats just use `'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post-format',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'post-format-quote' )
                    )
                )
` to get only your wanted post type

Comment: Where's the post format specific code in your query then? +1 Bainternet..

Comment: @Bainternet I haven't been able to get the tax_query to work for me with the query I use above. If you can be specific it would be helpful.

Comment: Just a heads up the codex was wrong the other day, I think it is now changed,   it is `'taxonomy' => 'post_format'` . Underscore not hyphen. This is for Bainternet's comment , it looks right in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer after some more hunting. Apparently the only way to pull the standard posts is to add:

```
'operator' => 'NOT IN',
```

So it looks for posts that aren't in the image post format. Or I have to add an array of terms to the terms line so it won't return any of those formats. Odd, but it works.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'post__not_in' => $ids, 
  'showposts' => 10, 
  'cat' => '-4,-1866,-27',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'post-format-image',
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
  )
);  
    query_posts( $args ); ?>
<!-- The Loop -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I understand `tax_query`, doing a `NOT IN` query to exclude all formats except for the standard one would be an extremely slow performance-wise.