# How to exclude posts of a certain format from the feed

Tags: feed, post-formats

I want to exclude posts from aside post-format in the feed. I have already checked up [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12726/help-altering-a-query-to-exclude-all-but-standard-post-format) about how to exclude posts from a certain post format from the loop but how to exclude posts from a post format in the feed? Couldn't modify it because I am not very good with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the feed, you should hook into the main query that WordPress will do on every page request. The best hook here is `pre_get_posts`. This code example will hook into `pre_get_posts`, check whether it is a feed, and add the post format taxonomy query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse18412_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse18412_pre_get_posts( &$wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_feed() ) {
        $post_format_tax_query = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-image', // Change this to the format you want to exclude
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $tax_query = $wp_query->get( 'tax_query' );
        if ( is_array( $tax_query ) ) {
            $tax_query = $tax_query + $post_format_tax_query;
        } else {
            $tax_query = array( $post_format_tax_query );
        }
        $wp_query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried your code but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @navjotjsingh: Indeed, my code contained a small error: the taxonomy query is an array of arrays. I tested and corrected my example.